# Evaluating Keys value issues in JS

Tags: javascript

You are given an object called sumMe containing several key/value pairs and a variable called total whose initial value is 0. Using a for... in loop, iterate through the keys of sumMe; if the value corresponding to a key is a number, add it to total

can someone please explain why I'm getting zero for my result? total should equal 15.

```js
const sumMe = {
  hello: 'there',
  you: 8,
  are: 7,
  almost: '10',
  done: '!'
};

let total = 0;

// iterate by using for...in loop
for (let i in sumMe) {
  // corresponding to a key is a number by using object and value 
  if (typeof Object.values(sumMe) === 'number') {
    // adding the results and total should equal 15.
    total += Object.values(sumMe);
  }
}

// print out 
console.log(total);
```

Comment: Because `if` condition is not matched so return pre-defined total = 0

Comment: `typeof Object.values(sumMe) === 'number'` will _never_ match. `Object.values` will always return an array (`typeof` will log "object").

Comment: Replace all `Object.values(sumMe)` with `sumMe[i]`. You can read more about property accessors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make corrections when getting current values in the loop.

```js
const sumMe = {
  hello: 'there',
  you: 8,
  are: 7,
  almost: '10',
  done: '!'
};

let total = 0;

// iterate by using for...in loop
for (let i in sumMe) {
  // corresponding to a key is a number by using object and value 
  if (typeof sumMe[i] === 'number') {
    // adding the results and total should equal 15.
    total += sumMe[i];
  }
}

// print out 
console.log(total);
```